# Replace Text in val with array - jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays

I am looking to replace text in a text area value with an array. I have already seen how to replace the text with a value

```
$("#mySelector").val(function(i, v) { //index, current value
return v.replace("#","Custom Text");
});
```

But I have multiple items to replace. I have tried && between multiple values but I am clearly doing something wrong.

Here is what I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#submit').click(function() {

    var array = [];

    array[0] = '#1', 'Value 1';
    array[1] = '#2', 'Value 2';
    array[2] = '#3', 'Value 3';


    $('#article').val(function(i,v) {
            return v.replace(
            '$VET','Sebastian Vettel' &&
            '$VETf','Sebastian'
            );
    });
    return false;
});
});
```

The array is there, but I'd like to know how I can use it in the function for return v.replace. My jQuery is pretty basic, hence my issues. Any ideas are appreciated thanks.

Comment: What's `array[0] = '#1', 'Value 1';` supposed to do? It would only assign '#1' to array[0]. Are you sure you don't want to use an object instead? `obj['#1']='Value 1'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate through the array and replace

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#submit').click(function () {

        var array = [];

        array[0] = ['#1', 'Value 1'];
        array[1] = ['#2', 'Value 2'];
        array[2] = ['#3', 'Value 3'];

        $('#article').val(function (i, v) {
            $.each(array, function (i, arr) {
                v = v.replace(arr[0], arr[1]);
            })
            return v;
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sUY69/)

Comment: On first use everything appeared to work, but if I have something like '#1a' in array one it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace more than one string, you should use several `.replace()` methods:

```
return v.replace('str1','Sebastian Vettel')
        .replace('str2','Sebastian');
```

Instead of using multiple `.replace()` methods you can also use an object:

```
var chars = {
   '#1': 'Value 1',
   '#2': 'Value 2'
};

$('#article').val(function(i, v) {
    for(k in chars) {
       if (chars.hasOwnProperty(k)) 
         v = v.replace(k, chars[k]);
    }
    return v;
});
```

Comment: Cool. Wondered if it was best to use multiple replace methods or have one large array.

Comment: @devon93 If you want to use an array, you should iterate through it and then use the `.replace()` method for each array's element.

Answer (score 0):

You need to chain your replaces together like this:

.     $(document).ready(function() {

$('#submit').click(function() {

```
var array = [];

array[0] = '#1', 'Value 1';
array[1] = '#2', 'Value 2';
array[2] = '#3', 'Value 3';


$('#article').val(function(i,v) {
        return v.replace(
        '$VET','Sebastian Vettel').replace(
        '$VETf','Sebastian'
        );
});
return false;
```

});
});